# Are users allowed to add information when editing a Story-Identification question?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, editing

### Are users allowed to edit information into a question when they think they are asking about the same story?

I have posted a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152438/trying-to-find-a-book-about-an-extraordinary-elevator/152442#152442) recently. I asked for the title of the book and the name of the author. I also included in the question that users can edit my question's grammatical errors, formatting, and content. I also wrote that they can edit the content if **they also don't know the title of the book but they know more information than the post.**

If so, are users allowed to edit information into the question when they feel they have additional information but don't know the name of the story?

For Example:
*A* asked a question about a book. *B* doesn't know the name of the book, but remembers additional information about a book that **might** be the one the question asks about. Can *B* edit the question to add more information or is that up to the user who asked the question?

Comment: TLDR; Don't be adding extra info to other people's Story-ID question. If you know the answer, answer it. If you don't know the answer, you might be thinking of a different property.

Comment: @Valorum oh yes. I thought adding a little info could make the question easier to be answered but it can also be mistaken by another book.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Information added to a story ID question by another user may change the meaning of the question because the other user (editor) may be recalling a similar but different story. According to the [help center's information on editing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), this is not the proper use of the editing privilege (emphasis added):

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Instead, the other user should post the information in a comment to the question and ask the OP if that information matches the story the OP is asking about. If the OP responds then any user can (and should) edit that information into the question (either that it *does* or *does not* match the story the OP is looking for) in order to help answerers identify the story. If the OP does not respond to the comment then that information should be left in the comments.

Comment: very well said!